# Please help me find bug in my Gradient descend implementation in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient, regression

i am trying to implement the gradient descend explained in the link http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf. The below code returns parameters which are exponentially large and if i increase the iterations, params reaches infinity. I have wasted 4 hours trying to figure out what's wrong. Please help guys.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

advertising_data = pd.read_csv("http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv", index_col=0)
target = np.array(advertising_data.Sales.values)
advertising_data["ones"] = np.ones(200)
advertising_data = advertising_data[["ones", "TV"]]
features = np.array(advertising_data.values)

def error_ols(target, features):
    def h(betas):
        error = target - np.dot(features, betas)
        return error
    return h

def ols_loss(errors):
    return np.sum(errors*errors)

def gradient_descend(initial_guess, learning_step, gradient, iterations = 10):
    for i in range(0, iterations):
        update = initial_guess + learning_step*gradient( initial_guess)
        initial_guess = update
        error = error_ols(target, features)(update)
        print ols_loss(error)

    return update

def ols_gradient(target, features):
    def h(betas):
        error =  target - np.dot(features, betas)
        return -np.dot(error, features)
    return h



gradient_function = ols_gradient(target, features)
initial_guess = np.array([1,1])
gradient_descend(initial_guess, 0.0001, gradient_function)
```

Comment: The code you have written appears nowhere in your link; it appears to be your own design. To say the time was "wasted" is poor form - you wrote the code. I understand the maths required for these things, now my job "forces" me to learn several totally new programming languages to implement it. I enjoy learning it; it can take **ages** for me to implement my theory into code, but it's **all** learning. No doubt I have written terribly long-winded code, but I have no problem explaining what it does to others. No matter how much I have tried, I cannot follow your code at all.

Answer (score 3):

Spent a long time going through this; treated it as an "attention to detail exercise."

```
def ols_gradient(target, features):
    def h(betas):
        error =  target - np.dot(features, betas)
        return np.dot(error, features)
    return h
```

Make sure to drop the learning rate to .0000001.

Funny how the smallest mistakes are the hardest to find.

Comment: I'm amazed you spent the time! it was always going to be a +/- problem :) Up-voted for the effort.

Comment: There is another issue, he is doing a full batch descent, but not dividing the gradient by the number of rows in the dataset. That's why you need such a low learning rate, otherwise 0.01 should be sufficient

Comment: @ProgrammingRain I tried to lower the learning rate as you suggested, but still the loss is increasing. And i don't understand why other implementations i looked over the net divide the loss by the number of rows. Dividing by a fixed number should not have an impact on the optimal values. Thanks for taking time out for my problem but it's still not yet resolved. Please help.